# remove duplicates in one column of an arraylist when multiple columns have duplicates

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates, resultset

I have a search function for documents which returns a result set from my database. i store this resultset in an arraylist to display in the front end. This arraylist contains the following fields. fileName(has duplicates), date (has duplicates), type (has duplicates) required(boolean, has duplicates). If a file name is repeated, i want to show it only once and also modify the corresponding columns in that row to show 'N/A'. i have been trying to use SET but without success. Let me know if you need more details.
For example:
Below is how i get my result set into an arraylist. Now lets say this arraylist has one

```
   String a= request.getParameter("name");
String cust = request.getParameter("custId");
String Type = request.getParameter("prodType");
ArrayList searchResult = msgDH.getSearchDtls(a,cust,Type);
```

(above function executes the procedure and returns a table of {fileName, date, type, required (y/n})

Now lets a sample filename 'Sample1' (among others)is repeated in the search results with different corresponding "type" values and same "date" and "required" values.. how can i show only one row with filename 'Sample1' and file type as 'n/a' or any other string.

Comment: Could you post the relevant code - it's hard to work out what's going on.

Comment: Please post if formatted into your question. What is your `ArrayList` _of_?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're using a `YourOwnObject`. Override `equals()` in your object to suit your needs and then put all those populated Objects in your `Set`. `Set` will remove the duplicates for you.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your database:

```
Select distinct file_name, data, type, required  
from my_database
```